# Magento 2 save custom value to quote

Tags: magento2, custom, quote

I have added an extra column, by using custom module (upgradeScheme), into the table **quote**. How can I save my custom value into this column when quote is created? The value I want to add to this extra column can I get from the session. I just don't know how I can save this value into the quote. Please give a step by step instruction.

If I sum up my situation, it would be,

1. I have added an extra column in the table quote.
2. I can get the value I want to add to the custom column from session.
3. I know how to convert/copy data from Quote to Order.
4. **I don't know** how to save my custom value to the extra column I created in Quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Use Event `checkout_cart_product_add_after`.

**in your frontend/events.xml**

```
<event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="after_add_to_cart" instance="your\module\Observer\AddToCartAfter" />
</event>
```

in observer file **AddToCartAfter.php**

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

    $quoteItem = ( $quoteItem->getParentItem() ? $quoteItem->getParentItem() : $quoteItem );

    $quoteItem->setCustomField("Custom Value");
    //here u set value of your field of quote

}
```

Comment: i want save custom value for quote_item table

Comment: If you have any idea please guide me

Comment: You can follow my answer for that.

Comment: Why did you answer a question that hadn't been asked yet (Hitesh's) instead of answering the OP's question? And why did the OP accept this answer? This clearly doesn't update the quote table. My search continues...